# Using SignalR as client side API scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr.client

I have seen lot of examples of using signalR in combination with API as push notification events for client to notify of updated data available. Is it possible to use SignalR as an client application that schedules REST API Calls in the case the server doesn't have any signalR service.  Here is what I am trying to do. I am client that uses API provided by vendor to make calls to pull data and map it to our database. There is no way of knowing that there is new data until I make a REST API call to check.

This is where I am thinking that the long poling feature of signalR would come in handy. Idea is to create a local executable application that uses SignalR to call the api to check if there is new data and then execute a service (another .net executable application) that will pull the data and consume it (map it to our database).

Can this work?

Comment: SignalR requires a server. It is not a schedule service. That's what Windows Task Scheduler, Quartz.NET, Hangfire etc are for.

Comment: Build a service application that will call the API every n timespan, get the new data if any and update the database

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i have opted to use a scheduler such as Autosys to call the console executable ever n times, rather than use signalR unconventionally.